# How can I access the firestore in asyncData?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

How can I access the firestore as a authenticated user in asyncData when this is null in the asyncData?

```
  async asyncData(){
    console.log(this);
    try{
      const data = await this.$fireStore
        .collection("users")
        .doc("dgsxhchdxfwsezgxrd")
        .collection("games").doc("test")
        .collection("verions").doc("v0.0.1").get();
        console.log(firestore success ${data});
        return{ gameData: data};
    }catch(error){
      console.log(firestore error ${error});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eggsy from the nuxt channel answered:

You don't have access to this in asyncData because it's rendered before the page is loaded. But you have access to Nuxt context which includes plugins, router etc. you can simply access the context with a parameter or choose what you want in it:

```
async asyncData(context) {
   // Access the fire store object
   context.$fireStore;
}

// or get it from the object
async asyncData({ $fireStore }) {
   $fireStore;
}
```